# How to exclude One action from default interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I want to exclude login action from my default interceptor without putting it a diffrent package

```xml
<default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
```

the action that i want to exclude is Login Action

```xml
<action name="loginUser" class="com.action.LoginAction" method="login">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't exclude actions from interceptors, you exclude interceptors from actions.

Specifically, if you want to use the `defaultStack` for your `login` action and the `loginStack` for all the other actions, you do:

```xml
<default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></default-interceptor-ref>

...

<action name="loginUser" class="com.action.LoginAction" method="login">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result>login.jsp</result>
</action>
```